# Get the backgroundworker from MainForm in a user control

Tags: c#

I have a form with a backgroundworker
when I click a button the backgroundworker starts with this code:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     M_Results m_Results = new M_Results();
     this.Controls.Add(m_Results);
     m_Results.Location = new Point(0, 0);
     m_Results.Visible = true;
}
```

in the user control Im trying to reporteprogress from the backgroundworker, what Ive done is:

```
   BackgroundWorker bgWorker;
   public Results()
   {
        Form mainform = this.Parent as Form;
        bgWorker = Padre.Controls["backgroundWorker"] as BackgroundWorker;
        InitializeComponent();
        Inicializartablas();
        Formatotablas();
   }
```

but I get error that I cant convert Form.control to backgroundworker.

thank you
Carlos

Comment: _"but I get error that I cant convert Form.control to backgroundworker"_ Backgroundworkers are not controls. How do expect `Padre.Controls` to contain one?

Comment: I dont know where is being contain, does why Im asking for help

Comment: How can _we_ know? We cannot see your full code. Have your IDE search for "new BackgroundWorker" ... then you should find where it is created and stored (if it is in the first place).

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is not a `Control` so you will never find it in the `Controls` collection. You need to rethink how your user control is getting information from the parent form.

Comment: You'll have to re-think this, a BGW cannot call Controls.Add().  As written, there is no need to use a BGW at all.

Answer (score 0):

A `BackgoundWorker` does not inherit from `Control` and though is'nt added to the Controls List. You may utilize the existing Reporting API of the BackroundWorker. You can hook the `ProgressChanged`Event and raise it using the `ReportProgress` Method.